# Разные куки на поддоменах

Tags: php, cookie, поддомены

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы куки для домена **[domain.ru](http://domain.ru)** НЕ распространялись на поддомены типа **[any.domain.ru](http://any.domain.ru)**

Моя функция для записи куков:

```
/**
* @param string $name
* @param string $value
* @param integer $live_time
*/
private function set_cookies($name, $value = '', $live_time = 0)
{       
    // $this->domain == "domain.ru" Без точки...
    if($live_time) $live_time = time() + ($live_time * 86400); else $live_time = false;     
    @setcookie($name, $value, $live_time, '/', $this->domain, null, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

[domain.ru](http://domain.ru) - перенести на [www.domain.ru](http://www.domain.ru) (куки соответсвенно ставить для [www.donain.ru](http://www.donain.ru))

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению не подойдет. По условию ТЗ головной домен должен быть без www + неограниченное число произвольных поддоменов